# Build Graph given a SuccessorsFunction and a set of nodes

Tags: guava, graph-theory

I would like to build a Guava [`ImmutableGraph`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/graph/ImmutableGraph.html) given a set of nodes (starting points) and a [`SuccessorsFunction`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/graph/SuccessorsFunction.html). The graph would contain all the nodes reachable from any of the starting node and all the edges seen on the way thanks to the `SuccessorsFunction`. (E.g., given starting node `{a}` and successors `a → b` and `b → c`, the resulting graph should be `{(a, b), (b, c)}`.)

I see how I can obtain a [`Traverser`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/graph/Traverser.html) to explore the reachable nodes in a certain order, given starting nodes and a `SuccessorsFunction`, but it does not meet my needs as I want to obtain a graph, not just the nodes.

It is not very hard to define an algorithm that does this, but it’s subtle enough to deserve trying to re-use an existing solution. I would be surprised if it didn’t exist already in the library. Does it? Or is this requirement not sensible?

I didn’t find this in the related [wiki](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/GraphsExplained) page.

Comment: Is there a reason not to just loop over the nodes, call your successor function for each one, and call `putEdge` in a Builder for each pair?

Comment: @LouisWasserman do you mean, looping over just the provided starting nodes? That will miss out some edges. (I just added an example.)

Comment: Am I right to think that you want to do a breadth-first (or depth-first) traversal from your starting nodes to their children, then their grandchildren, and so on and so forth for all descendants (according to your `SuccessorsFunction`), and for every node encountered to add it and its children to your graph, connected together with edges? If so then, no, Guava doesn't have this out of the box.

Comment: @jbduncan yes, but keeping in mind that the successors may loop (a→b→a), so a (too naïve) traversal would risk cycling.

Comment: Related [issue](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/3754) on Guava.

Comment: FYI there's a design out for review inside Google to address this specific need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guava doesn't have this feature built in, so you'll need a custom solution that does some sort of graph traversal (like breadth-first traversal), like the following code snippet.

```java
public static <N> ImmutableGraph<N> buildGraphWithBreadthFirstTraversal(
    Iterable<N> startingNodes, SuccessorsFunction<N> successorsFunction) {
  MutableGraph<N> result = GraphBuilder.directed().allowsSelfLoops(true).build();
  startingNodes.forEach(result::addNode);
  Queue<N> nodesRemaining = Queues.newArrayDeque(startingNodes);
  while (!nodesRemaining.isEmpty()) {
    N next = nodesRemaining.remove();
    for (N successor : successorsFunction.successors(next)) {
      if (!result.edges().contains(EndpointPair.ordered(next, successor))) {
        nodesRemaining.add(successor);
        result.putEdge(next, successor);
      }
    }
  }
  return ImmutableGraph.copyOf(result);
}
```

Here is a basic JUnit 5 unit test that confirms the code works when given a starting node and a `successorsFunction` that together form a cycle of `1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 1`.

```java
@Test
void succeedsOnTraversalWithCycle() {
  var result =
      MoreGraphs.buildGraphWithBreadthFirstTraversal(
          ImmutableList.of(1),
          node -> {
            int nextNode = node * 2;
            return nextNode <= 4 ? ImmutableList.of(nextNode) : ImmutableList.of(1);
          });

  assertThat(result)
      .isEqualTo(
          GraphBuilder.directed()
              .allowsSelfLoops(true)
              .immutable()
              .putEdge(1, 2)
              .putEdge(2, 4)
              .putEdge(4, 1)
              .build());
}
```

Comment: @Olivier Cailloux I think it's worth mentioning that you may be able to optimise the memory usage of this code by removing the `visited` set and `visited.add(successor)` call, and in turn replacing the graph builder with a `MutableGraph`, replacing `!visited.contains(successor)` with `!mutableGraph.nodes().contains(successor)`, and replacing `return builder.build()` with `return ImmutableGraph.copyOf(mutableGraph)`.

Comment: I now have a GitHub repo containing this code: https://github.com/jbduncan/guava-graph-utils. It doesn't have additional tests beyond the unit test in my answer above, though, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: My GitHub repo now has more tests, which caught a bug I had in my example above regarding circular graphs; rather than returning `{(1, 2), (2, 4)}`, the code now returns `{(1, 2), (2, 4), (4, 1)}`.